# Reading the same file but getting different bytes

Tags: scala, hash

In a foldleft, I am trying to digest different images.  I got frustrated and decided to read the same file and I received different byte arrays for reading the same file!  Does anyone know why this is happening?  Here is the code where it is happening, "swap.png" is never changed during the run

```
  val capturedImage = outputScreen.capture
  val swap = new File("swap1.png")
  ImageIO.write(capturedImage, "png", swap)
  val bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("swap.png"))
  val byte = Stream.continually(bis.read).takeWhile(-1 !=).map(_.toByte).toArray
  println(byte.toString)
```

Here is some output

```
[B@31302ed5
[B@3a56d071
[B@6039d718
[B@3490e5eb
[B@2f29608e
[B@4c09c5c3
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're getting is toString representation of array of bytes (because of `[B`) which defaults to [Object.toString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29). What does Object.toString do? Typically, it just prints internal info about where object is in the memory (so called [identity hash](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#identityHashCode%28java.lang.Object%29))*. So it is perfectly fine to have different objects at different RAM memory locations at different runs thus different output. Try instead of doing this issue `.mkString(",")` in last line:

```
println(byte.mkString(","))
```

* but there might be different implementations

Comment: Holy crap thank you!  I was pulling my hair out on that one.  Learn something new every day